# postgresql trigger to compare the third to last character with an attribute

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have recently started studying PostgreSQL and am having trouble creating triggers.
In the specific case I should check that a male athlete cannot participate in a competition for women and vice versa; in the match_code attribute an 'M' or an 'F' is inserted as the third to last character to identify that the race is for males or females (for example: 'Q100x4M06'); only one character, 'M' or 'F', is stored in the gender attribute.
I would therefore need to understand how to compare them and activate the trigger when they are not correctly entered in the participation table.
This is what i have assumed but i know it is wrong, it is just an idea, can someone help me?

```
CREATE FUNCTION check()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    x VARCHAR;
    y VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SELECT match_code INTO x FROM race;
    SELECT gender INTO y FROM athlete;
    IF $x LIKE '&$y__' == athlete.gender
        THEN
        RETURN new;
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION $$It is not possible to add an athlete of a gender that is not compatible with the competition$$;
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

```
CREAT TRIGGER triggerCheck
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON participation
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check();
```

below are the definitions of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE race (
    ID_g SERIAL NOT NULL,
    code_race VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY,
    r_date DATE,
    discipline VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE athlete (
    ID_a SERIAL NOT NULL,
    code_athlete INT CHECK (codice_atleta >= 0 AND codice_atleta <= 15000) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (30),
    surname VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    nation VARCHAR (3) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR CHECK (gender = 'M' OR gender = 'F'),
    b_date DATE,
    sponsor VARCHAR (20)
);

CREATE TABLE participation (
    ID_p SERIAL NOT NULL,
    codR VARCHAR (20) REFERENCES race (code_race) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    codA INT REFERENCES athlete (code_athlete) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    arrival_order INT CHECK (arrival_order > 0),
    r_time TIME DEFAULT '00:00:00.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (codG, codA)
);
```

Comment: Can you please share the definition of the tables "race", athlete" and "participation" including the foreign keys ? In particular, how does the table "particiation" refer to the tables "race" and "athlete" ?

Comment: I updated by adding the table definitions

Comment: What is the column "match_code" that you reference in the proposed check() trigger function?  Did you mean to make this field "race"."code_race"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tables definition, your trigger function should be someting like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION check()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $BODY$
BEGIN       
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM race AS r
                 INNER JOIN athlete AS a
                    ON r.code_race ~ (a.gender  || '..$')
                 WHERE r.code_race = NEW.codR
                   AND a.code_athlete = NEW.codA
              ) 
    THEN
        RETURN NEW ;
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'It is not possible to add an athlete of a gender that is not compatible with the competition';
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

In a function called by a trigger, you can (have to) use the variable `NEW` (resp. `OLD`) so that to refer to the new row (resp. the old row) to be inserted or updated (resp. only to be updated) in the targeted table (`"participation"` in your case) see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

The proposed function doesn't need to declare any variable, as the test can be performed directly through the proposed `sql` query.

The proposed sql query :

- First search for the rows in table `"race"` whose `code_race` equals the inserted/updated value of participation.codR = `NEW.codR`
- Then search for the rows in table `"athlete"` whose `code_athlete` equals
  the inserted/updated value of participation.codA = `NEW.codA`
- Finally compare the selected rows from both tables `"race"` and
  `"athlete"` using a *regular expression* to compare the `code_race` with
  the `gender` values, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

By the way,

(a) I don't see the added value of the columns ID of type `serial` in the tables definition, especially as they are not used in any primary key nor foreign key.

(b) The significant codification defined for the `code_race` attribute (for instance : 3rd last character defining the gender, an other character defining the competition level, ...) is a quite old-fashion practice that was used 30 years ago when the computer sciences had limited capacities and performances. In a more up-to-date approach, I would suggest you to manage these meaningful information in dedicated columns of the table `"race"`, and then, if you really need a significant composite `code_race`, to implement it as a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) :

```
CREATE TABLE race 
( ID_g SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, gender_race CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (gender_race IN ('M', 'F'))
, competition_level VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL CHECK (competition_level IN ('Q-Qualifiers', 'H-Heats', 'S-Semifinals', 'F=Finals'))
, code_race VARCHAR (20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ID_g :: text || '-' || discipline || '-' || gender_race || '-' || left(competition_level, 1)) STORED
, r_date DATE NOT NULL
, discipline VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
);
```

see the result in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f2733d4bd0447011d484fe67b639a534).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will try to study the manual a bit and implement your solution. I had added the ID columns assuming to have to use them to create other columns composed by the union of the various IDs but I still haven't thought about how to do it, for example I would like code_race to be composed of a letter (Q: qualifiers, H: heats, S: semifinals, F: finals), a number representing the category (e.g. archery) and another letter for gender

Comment: Answer updated according to your last comment.

Comment: thank you very much for the precise answers, I believe that I will follow your advice and create dedicated columns to make the tables.
however, it was helpful to see how to do it, even just as an exercise.